# Register a Visual Studio 2005/2008 package

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, registration, vspackage

I have an existing VSPackage that was originally developed in Visual Studio 2005. Since then the package has been converted into a Visual Studio 2008 project but still retains compatibility with Visual Studio 2005.

The problem I am having is that when I run regpkg it complains with the following error:

> regpkg : error : None of the packages define a registry root.

But I have defined a registry root as follows:

```
[DefaultRegistryRoot("Software\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\9.0")]
```

To convert the project, I remember following the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512930%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Any ideas?

All I want to do is export the registration information into a .reg file so that I can include it in an installer.

Thanks,
Alan